# What is a forged redirect? (in the context of javascript's fetch API)

Tags: javascript, http-response, es6, redirect

I'm trying to make sense of the docs located at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/redirected

It says

> Note: Relying on `redirected` to filter out redirects makes it easy for
> a **forged redirect** to prevent your content from working as expected.
> Instead, you should do the filtering when you call fetch(). See the
> example Disallowing redirects, which shows this being done.

and

> Because using `redirected` to manually filter out redirects can allow
> **forgery of redirects**, you should instead set the redirect mode to
> "error" in the init parameter when calling fetch(), like this:

Is it really possible to forge the `redirected` property on a fetch response somehow and how is that done? If not then what vulnerability is this talking about?

Comment: This might be in reference to [Server Side Request Forgery attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Server_Side_Request_Forgery) although I would need to do more research on this topic.

Comment: I don't think they are talking about faking the `redirected` property. I'm pretty sure they are talking about some sort of vulnerability in how servers redirect some requests, although I'm not sure how disallowing redirects is safer than checking this in your code...

Comment: `Response.redirect` is not what gets forged, it's request redirections. `fetch()` options also supports the property `redirect` which sets the strategy (allow/follow redirects, reject or manual handling). The post is aiming you to don't check/assert redirections when they already happened, instead choose the proper strategy when calling `fetch()`

Comment: @Laiv What does that mean when you say request redirections get forged?

Comment: Browser#fetch sends a request to point A, but it gets  a response generated by point Z. Browser's response object informs about this redirection via `Response.redirected`. In other words, by the time the browser gets the response, all the redirections (if any) already happened. In other to avoid fetching responses generated by redirections, `fetch()` implements different redirection policies. One of them (error) will reject any response generated by redirections.

Comment: Are you talking about a man in the middle attack?